# After my image blits in pygame, it falls and I don't know why

Tags: python, image, pygame

I got my images loaded and everything, but now when I call it, it's too big and I can't change the size and it won't stay where I called it and I can't see where I went wrong and why it keeps falling...the image blits and it shows up, but in the wrong place and it just fall, I can move the cat and all, but it's falling and it shouldn't. It's kind of like objects in a game that fall from the top of the screen and then they reload at the top, but then it doesn't reload. The cat needs to blit and be on the ground, but it's not.

```
import pygame
import os
import sys
from pygame.locals import*

pygame.init()

W = 800
H = 447
win = pygame.display.set_mode((W,H))
pygame.display.set_caption('A journey')

bg = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/background.png')).convert()

walkRight = [pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/R1.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/R2.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/R3.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/R4.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/R5.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/R6.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/R7.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/R8.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/R9.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/R10.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/R11.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/R12.png'))]

walkLeft = [pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/L1.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/L2.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/L3.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/L4.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/L5.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/L6.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/L7.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/L8.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/L9.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/L10.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/L11.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/L12.png'))]

runRight =[pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RR1.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RR2.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RR3.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RR4.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RR5.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RR6.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RR7.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RR8.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RR9.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RR10.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RR11.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RR12.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RR13.png'))]

runLeft = [pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LR1.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LR2.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LR3.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LR4.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LR5.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LR6.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LR7.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LR8.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LR9.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LR10.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LR11.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LR12.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LR13.png'))]

jumpRight = [pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LJ1.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LJ2.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LJ3.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LJ4.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LJ5.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LJ6.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LJ7.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LJ8.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LJ9.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LJ10.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LJ11.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LJ12.png'))]

jumpLeft = [pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RJ1.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RJ2.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RJ3.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RJ4.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RJ5.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RJ6.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RJ7.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RJ8.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RJ9.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RJ10.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RJ11.png')),
             pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/RJ12.png'))]

sit = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/LS6.png'))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

x = 50
y = 150
width = 94
height = 3.9
vel = 5
isJump = False
jumpCount = 10
left = False
right = False
walkCount = 0


def redrawWindow():
    global walkCount
    win.blit(bg, (0,0))

    if walkCount + 1 >= 27:
        walkCount = 0
    if left:
        win.blit(walkLeft[walkCount//3], (x, y))
        walkCount += 1
    elif right:
        win.blit(walkRight[walkCount//3], (x, y))
        walkCount += 1
    else:
        win.blit(sit, (x, y))

    pygame.display.flip()
    pygame.display.update()


# main loop
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(27)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
        x -= vel
        left = True
        right = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < W - width - vel:
        x += vel
        right = True
        left = False
    else:
        right = False
        left = False
        walkCount = 0

    if not(isJump):
        y += vel
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True
            right = False
            left = False
            walkCount = 0     
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            neg = 1
            if jumpCount < 0:
                neg = -1
            y -= (jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            isJump = False
            jumpCount = 10

    redrawWindow()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Do you mean "it fails" afterwards?

Comment: no, it falls, it blits and then falls...it's crazy and I don't know how to fix it...kinda like in a game when objects are falling from the sky and the go off the screen...it's like that, but then the cat never reloads, but it should blit on the ground and stay there, but it doesn't

Comment: OK. In that case I suggest you [edit] your question and add enough code so it's runnable and folks can use it to reproduce (and fix) the problem.

Comment: All those `os.path.join(...)` calls are superfluous, since you're not joining paths.  I guess it used to be something like `IMAGE_DIR="D:/Python/Buttons/Programs/Pygame/game/"` and `pygame.image.load(os.path.join(IMAGE_DIR, 'LJ1.png'))`

Comment: Kingsley, could I just get rid of the os.path.joins??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code looks to be processing the code for "jump" without having actually received the event for it.  Read through the event loop:

```
while run:
    clock.tick(27)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
       # do left
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < W - width - vel:
        #do right
    else:
        # neither left nor right

    if not(isJump):
        y += vel                      # <--- THIS PART
        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            # start a new jump
```

If the jump is not in progress, `y` is increased by `vel` (5) every frame.